# Removal of proposed updates

Tags: macos, software-update

I don't want to update my epson printer driver since I'm informed that it's likely Epson's method of preventing the use of non-Epson cartridges. Is there a way to stop the proposed update from popping up every morning when I start iTunes ?

Comment: Where does the update pop up from? Is it the generic Software Update popup for Apple downloads or something Epson specific?

Comment: What I'd like to do is remove it from the list of updates so that I do not continually get the popup message from iTunes every morning.

Answer (score 1):

There are two places the pop up can come from.

1. Apple store web site
2. Epson software that you installed on your computer.

If it is Apple-- If you right-click on the Update button you get the option to hide the update.

If it is the Epson Connect Printer Setup Utility v1.30 on your computer find it and select NO-auto updates.